# MobileFirst 7.1 - Build hybrid app for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I developed an hybrid app for Windows Phone with MobileFirst v7.1 but I don't know what is the procedure to compile the app to be installed on smartphone. I only know that Visual Studio is necessary, but searching in the web I didn't found any specific guide or documentation for achieve this task.

Answer (score 1):

You build your app in MobileFirst Studio as you build any other MobileFirst-based app

This generates a native project, in this case for Visual Studio.

You then need to open this project in Visual Studio, and from there on you follow standard Visual Studio guidelines (for this, search Microsoft's website for Windows Phone developers).